# Tomcat not picking up Log4j config for its internal logging

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j

I am trying to reconfigure Tomcat 7 to use log4j for its internal logging.

I have followed all steps in Tomcat 7 docs: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html 
It is still not using Log4J or atleast it is not using the config specified in the log4j.properties file.

What I have tried so far:

- Copied the necessary jar files to the locations mentioned in Tomcat
  Docs
- `CATALINA_HOME`, `CATALINA_BASE` environment variables were not
  present. Added them and set both to `C:\Program Files\Apache Software
  Foundation\Tomcat 7.0`
- Noticed that log4J properties file had references to 
  `catalina.base` instead of catalina_base so created , catalina.base
  and `catalina.home` environment variables and set both to `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0`
- As suggested [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20476251/681671) I have deleted the "auto" entries in the Monitor Tomcat App.
  [image]

lib/log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, CATALINA

# Define all the appenders
log4j.appender.CATALINA = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CATALINA.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/catalina
log4j.appender.CATALINA.Append = true
log4j.appender.CATALINA.Encoding = UTF-8
# Roll-over the log once per day
log4j.appender.CATALINA.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.LOCALHOST = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/localhost
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.Append = true
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOCALHOST.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.MANAGER = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MANAGER.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/manager
log4j.appender.MANAGER.Append = true
log4j.appender.MANAGER.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.MANAGER.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.MANAGER.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MANAGER.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.File = ${catalina.base}/logs/host-manager
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.Append = true
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.HOST-MANAGER.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.CONSOLE = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

# Configure which loggers log to which appenders
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost] = INFO, LOCALHOST
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager] =\
  INFO, MANAGER
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager] =\
  INFO, HOST-MANAGER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CATALINA_HOME defaults to Tomcat's installation directory.  You can set it if you like, but it's not necessary, particularly if you are running a simple single instance.  Additionally, you only need the underscore versions of the environment variables.  The 'dot' versions are referenced via Java rather than the shell - Tomcat knows where/how to get this information.

It would help if you say exactly which jars you put where - there might be something small you have missed, but without knowing precisely what you have done, it is impossible to say.  Also, you might want to make sure you have set the environment variables correctly.  Open a command prompt and type `echo %CATALINA_HOME%` and `echo %CATALINA_BASE%` to be sure.  Compare the output to the output of the `dir` command against those same directories.  Do they match?  Hint:  check for tilde (~) abbreviations.

Finally, are you absolutely certain it is not using log4j?  I ask because the log4j.properties file at the site to which you have linked is supposed to behave the same as Tomcat's out-of-the-box logging.  If you have just copied that file without changing anything, log4j might actually be working after all.

Comment: I have updated the question details with the config file. I expect to see more log files than what it I see in the logs directory. So I assume its not working.

Comment: I have put the files appropriate directories as mentioned in the document : "Put log4j.jar and tomcat-juli-adapters.jar from "extras" into $CATALINA_HOME/lib.
Replace $CATALINA_HOME/bin/tomcat-juli.jar with tomcat-juli.jar from "extras"."

Comment: However in the latest version of Log4J there is no log4j.jar. There are a dozen jars in its distro. I have put  log4j-api-2.2.jar and log4j-core-2.2 jar after reading http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#which_jars

Comment: Ok, found it. It seems log4j 2.x is significantly different from log4j 1.x. I got rid of the 2.x jars and put a 1.4 jar. It's working now. Thanks.