# Tomcat 7- Change location of log files

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I am running tomcat7 on ubuntu 14.04. I need to change the folder location for the log file:
/var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out

I tried the following:

1. Set environment variable CATALINA_OUT in the /etc/environment file to my custom location:
   CATALINA_OUT=/xyz/catalina.out
2. In the /etc/tomcat7/logging.properties, i updated the below property:
   1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = /xyz
   (this starting saving catalina.2016-03-19.log files to my custom location; instead of the catalina.out)

Neither of the above work for me. Please help. Thanks
Jaskaran

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem with tomcat 8.5.*

I followed the advice from rod.poli.diniz and did the following:
Created an environment variable in my  `~/bash_profile`

```
export CATALINA_LOGS_1=/home/user1/apps/logs/app1
```

In tomcat `<tomcat-base>/bin/setenv.sh` added the following JVM argument that is identified in `<tomcat-base>/conf/logging.properties`.

```
-Dcatalina.logs=$CATALINA_LOGS_1
```

Then updated `<tomcat-base>/conf/logging.properties`.

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.logs}/catalina
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.logs}/catalina
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.logs}/catalina
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.logs}/catalina
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = host-manager.
```

#### Result:

In `<tomcat-base>/logs/`:

```
catalina.out
localhost_access_log.2019-04-12.txt
tomcat.pid
```

In `$CATALINA_LOGS_1`:

```
catalina.2019-04-12.log
host-manager.2019-04-12.log
localhost.2019-04-12.log
manager.2019-04-12.log
```

#### Expected:

In `<tomcat-base>/logs/`:

```
tomcat.pid
```

In `$CATALINA_LOGS_1`:

```
catalina.out
localhost_access_log.2019-04-12.txt
catalina.2019-04-12.log
host-manager.2019-04-12.log
localhost.2019-04-12.log
manager.2019-04-12.log
```

#### Solution:

Update `<tomcat-base>/bin/setenv.sh` with the following:

```
mkdir -p $CATALINA_LOGS_1
CATALINA_OUT=$CATALINA_LOGS_1/catalina.out
```

Update `<tomcat-base>/conf/server.xml` find the AccessLogValve. Replace `directory="logs"`: --> `directory="${cfrm.logs}"`

Answer (score 1):

The default place for tomcat logging configuration is:

CATALINA_HOME/conf/logging.properties.

You need to edit this file if you want to change the logging location. For tomcat 7 you have like this inside the file:

```
############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager.
```

You need to replace ${catalina.base}/logs to your desired new directory/path. That is for tomcat's core logging. For your web application you should do that inside your specific application's log4j or other logging framework.

Answer (score 1):

## You can change the logging file location by two ways:

**Method 1.)** For example to write log files in "D:/logs" path, edit /tomcat7/config/logging.properties as like shown below and restart the tomcat service.

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = D:/logs

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = D:/logs

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = D:/logs

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = D:/logs

Note: It only write log files like catalina, manager, host-manager, commons-deamon.

If you want to write stdout and stderr file also in the same path, follow second method.

**Method 2).** Go to /tomcat7/bin/ and open Tomcatw.exe with administrator rights -> Logging tab -> At Log path specify D:\logs. Apply settings and restart the tomcat service.

Note: Before applying the changes kindly check READ/WRITE permission given to appropriate user that the tomcat used (Log On) to run it's service.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below to change `Tomcat` Log Locations as you prefer:

This is for **Linux:** and should be mostly the same for Windows as well.

Locate the tomcat installed location: `<tomcat-base>/conf/logging.properties`

```
catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = <add_location_you_prefer>
catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.

localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = <add_location_you_prefer>
localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = localhost.

manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = <add_location_you_prefer>
manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = manager.

host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = <add_location_you_prefer>
host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = host-manager.
```

Finally you will need to change the `catalina.out`:

Locate the following code snippet in `Catalina.sh` script in bin directory of your tomcat base location:

```
if [ -z "$CATALINA_OUT" ] ; then
  CATALINA_OUT="$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out
fi
```

Change the

`CATALINA_OUT="$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out`

to:

`CATALINA_OUT=<add_location_you_prefer>/catalina.out`